# Logging stdout and stderr separately and together simultaneously

Tags: perl, bash, terminal, stdout, stderr

I have a specific problem I'd like to solve and I'm running `system` through `perl` which I think runs in `bash`:

1. Show `stdout` and `stderr` in `both.log`. Add "done" if it finished.
2. **Append** `stderr` in `stderr.log`
3. Don't print out to terminal, except the original command and "done" if the command finished.

So once we combine `stdout` and `stderr`, can we separate them again? OR can we first capture `stderr` and then combine it with `stdout` after?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

bash: `system("((" . $cmd . " 2>&1 1>&3 | tee -a stderr.log) 3>&1) > both.log; echo done | tee -a both.log"`

Even though we use `tee` for `stderr.log` it doesn't `tee` the error output to the terminal (which is what I want). I don't completely understand how it works, but I guess the `tee` causes it to go to the log file and also to the next file descriptor equation.

---

**Bonus**

I found this here in the comments: http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/howto/redirection_tutorial
This can be used to do the same thing, but all output is also `tee`d to terminal (It doesn't print "done").

bash:
`(($command 2>&1 1>&3 | tee stderr.log) 3>&1 ) | tee both.log`

---

Using Perl 5.14.1.

Answer (score 0):

`tcsh` alone would not suffice here. It does not support redirecting stderr without stdout.

Use another shell or a designated script.

More [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13720246/redirect-stderr-to-stdout-in-c-shell).

---

**UPDATE:**

> Can this be ported to tcsh?

No. tcsh does not support redirecting stderr without stdout.

Comment: I have access to bash and zsh too, but they aren't preferred. Updating question.

Comment: removed `tcsh` from question` since I am calling `system` through `perl` and I believe it is using `bash`. Also modified the question significantly, since I don't need `tee` anymore.