# How to redirect command line outputs to a file, but still show them in the command line?

Tags: linux, shell, tcsh

In `tcsh` I want to redirect command line outputs to a file, but I still want to show them in the command line.

Did a little bit search that

```
./MyCommand.sh 2>&1 | tee /tmp/Output.txt
```

should do the job. But I got an error like:

```
Ambiguous output redirect
```

Comment: Is `./MyCommand.sh 2>&1` alone working fine to you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use of `2>&1` to combine stderr and stdout works only in `bash` and `sh`. It does not for `csh` or `tcsh`. A work around is suggested at [Redirect stdout to stderr in tcsh](https://superuser.com/questions/427929/redirect-stdout-to-stderr-in-tcsh).

Answer (score 0):

In `bash` instead of `2>&1` I use `|&`
Not sure how this plays out for `tcsh`, but this question isn't currently tagged for it and hoping this helps someone else.

According to this [redirect stderr to stdout in c shell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13720246/redirect-stderr-to-stdout-in-c-shell) you can't do this in `csh` which `tcsh` extends which could be related

Answer (score 0):

It isn't clear from the question if you want to redirect stdout only, or stdout and stderr.

Using `|` will redirect stdout to `tee` (which outputs it to a file and to terminal), leaving stderr untouched (so it only goes to terminal):

```
./MyCommand.sh | tee /tmp/Output.txt
```

Using `|&` will "merge" stdout and stderr, and `tee` will redirect both to file and to terminal:

```
./MyCommand.sh |& tee /tmp/Output.txt
```