# Capture stdout (likely) with BSD grep

Tags: macos, grep, stdout, intel-fortran

I am trying to extract the version of fortran compiler using `ifort -v` command and then grep it check for version.

However this does not work.

```
%ifort -v
ifort version 16.0.1
%ifort -v | grep "version"
ifort version 16.0.1
%ifort -v | grep "xyz"
ifort version 16.0.1
```

It appears as if the output is getting printed irrespective of my pattern. So to test it out I tried the following redirection to null and it still printed. It seems likes the output is not going to the stdout.

```
%ifort -v > /dev/null
ifort version 16.0.1


%ifort -v 2>/dev/null
ifort: error #10236: file not found: '2'
ifort version 16.0.1
```

Is it possible that the information i see in shell is actually being written by a different process than the current executing ifort command and thats the reason I am unable to capture it?
How can I capture this and grep it?

Comment: Could you please try ifort -v 2> /dev/null ?

Comment: Edited to include redirecting the stderr. Seems like ifort has a different way of executing commands.

Comment: What is your shell? Could you execute echo $0

Comment: I am on tcsh shell however in bash ifort -v 2> /dev/null returns empty

Comment: In that case ifort writes to stderr. I do not know tcs but on bash you would simple do ifort -v  2>&1 | awk '{ print $2}' for example.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently the `ifort -v` writes to `stderr`. On bash redirecting `stderr` to `stdout` helps with that. The version could be obtained then for example using `ifort -v 2>&1 | awk '{ print $2}'`.

It looks like it is not [trivial](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13720246/redirect-stderr-to-stdout-in-c-shell) to redirect `stderr` to `stdout` on (t)csh and that `csh` family of shells is not [well suited](http://www.perl.com/doc/FMTEYEWTK/versus/csh.whynot) for scripting.

Comment: `ifort -v |& ...` may well be preferable.